# trying to find error of the connection string to external sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, string, connection

iam running asp.mvs web-application.
its already hosted and DB is also by same hosting provider.
i am trying (already 3 day) to use given `connection string` for transfering data from DB.
here is my method where is my `connection string.`
can you please take a look and see some potential mistake.
its very annoing because i cant do this simple thing.

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Gets connection string of Database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>connection string of type const</returns>
    public static string GetConnectionStringOfDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            string cnc = @"data source=OnlineVertrag.mssql.somee.com;workstation      id=OnlineVertrag.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id="xxx";pwd="xxx";persist security info=False;initial catalog=OnlineVertrag";
            return cnc;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bool rethrow = ExceptionHelper.Handle(ex, "Business Logic");
            if (rethrow)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }




 public bool CheckIfUserIsActive(string username)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLDataHelper.GetConnectionStringOfDatabase());

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT IsActive "
                                + "FROM Users "
                                + "WHERE Username = @Username";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", UserName));

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                bool isActiveValueFromDataBase = false;

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        isActiveValueFromDataBase = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsActive"]);
                        if (isActiveValueFromDataBase == true)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you open the connection somewhere else, because in the posted code you simply return a connection string. Maybe you need a port number besides the server adress? Have you tried connecting using the server's IP? Check www.connectionstrings.com for some examples.

Comment: iam calling connection string in all methods there i it need.

Comment: What error message do you receive when attempting to connect?  What connection information for the server does your hosting provider specify, or what provider do you have?  The error messages often contain the problem and hosting providers can often have specific non-default settings from named instances to port numbers.

Comment: if I trying to log-in on my webpage, its happens nothing despite DB has an user information. I'am dont getting any error, i suppose its wrong Connection String. but it is a string given from SQL Hosting provider. they are www.somee.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake #1: Posting login information in a public forum.

Seriously - everybody who views this page and looks at the edit history of the question can now login to your database. You should change the password ASAP.

Mistake #2: Storing a connection string in code. As you just saw - password changes can come quite unexpectedly. Easiest way: store in the web.config and use ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings to access them:

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2005/12/28/ASPNET-20-How-to-get-a-specific-ConnectionString-from-the-WebConfig-by-name.aspx

Possible mistake #3: Try "data source=OnlineVertrag.mssql.somee.com;user id=xxx;pwd=xxx;initial catalog=OnlineVertrag". Maybe the spaces between "workstation" and "id" are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What David Tischler said.

Do you have SQL Management Studio or another interactive SQL application that can use a connection string for connecting? At least in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 you can just paste your connection string into the "Additional Connection Parameters" section. I do not believe that this is there in earlier version.

How about you make a page where you try to connect to the DB, and then you display ex.Message as part of your page. Perhaps this will show you what the SQL client library thinks is wrong.